# Show a value using hover detail on rickshaw graph render

Tags: javascript, rickshaw

I'm using `Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail` to show values in a graph when moving the mouse over the graph.

Now, I would like to show an initial value from the graph - HoverDetail-style - when it has been loaded (before a `MouseEvent` gets fired for the graph).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the subclass example for my hover referenced [here](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/hover.html). At least with this, I was able to get my hover to appear on load by simulating the mouse event on the svg element:

```
e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent('mousemove', true, false);
rgraph[0].children[0].dispatchEvent(e)
```

This feels a bit hacky but seems to work okay (this example is using angular, but `rgraph[0].children[0]` would be the main graph svg element). Here is the above in context.

**Note:** You can also look at the source of [`examples/hover.js`](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/examples/hover.html) in the the [Rickshaw GitHub repository](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw).

```
var Hover = Rickshaw.Class.create(Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail, {
    render: function(args: any) {
        legend.innerHTML = args.formattedXValue;
        args.detail
            .sort((a: any, b: any) => { return a.order - b.order })
            .forEach(function(d: any) {
                var line = document.createElement('div');
                line.className = 'rline';
                var swatch = document.createElement('div');
                swatch.className = 'rswatch';
                swatch.style.backgroundColor = d.series.color;
                var label = document.createElement('div');
                label.className = 'rlabel';
                label.innerHTML = d.name + ": " + d.formattedYValue;
                line.appendChild(swatch);
                line.appendChild(label);
                legend.appendChild(line);
                var dot = document.createElement('div');
                dot.className = 'dot';
                dot.style.top = graph.y(d.value.y0 + d.value.y) + 'px';
                dot.style.borderColor = d.series.color;
                this.element.appendChild(dot);
                dot.className = 'dot active';
                this.show();
            }, this);
    }
});

var hover = new Hover({graph: graph});
e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent('mousemove', true, false);
rgraph[0].children[0].dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle! I will test this as soon as I have an opportunity!